# Connection between maximizing the number of dollar bills and the direction of steepest ascent?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

So I was studying multivariable calculus on Khanacademy and was going through their articles on the gradient and directional derivative. 
In one of the articles, Grant says that the dot product of two vectors is maximized when the two vectors are pointing in the same direction. 
He then proceeds to give this example:
Suppose I present to you a stack of 100 dollar bills, 100 bills, a stack of 20 dollar bills and a stack of 2 dollar bills. 
I explain that you should choose three different numbers A,B,C  that satisfy the equation
$$A^2 + B^2 + C^2 = 10404$$
And I will let you take A bills from the stack of 100 dollar , B bills from the 20 dollar stack,  C bills from the stack of 2 dollar bills.
So the natural question is, what choice of A,B and C maximizes the amount of money you get, and what is that maximum value?

How does this problem relate to maximizing the dot product of two vectors? And how would one go about solving it?